# JavaScript interfaces in MDN

Tags: javascript, interface

As far as I know JavaScript, being OOP based on prototypes - and not classes - do not contemplates interfaces, but relies instead on ducktyping.

I can often see however in MDN online documentation some objects described as "interfaces", such as Storage in here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage

Indeed window.Storage exists and is a function, but is not a constructor or a factory and fails if invoked. It has no members like the ones described in that page, as window.localStorage instead has.
The page

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

points window.Storage as the object accessed by window.localStorage. I understand that window.localStorage is a native object, but I would like to understand the role of window.Storage and why it is addressed by MDN as an "interface", in what sense: is it a specification to which browser developers adhere, rather than a strict "interface" as intended in class-based paradigm?

Thank you in advance, sorry for the strange question. Just trying to deepen my comprehension of ES.

Comment: Q: Why "contort" terminology applicable to other, different languages?  Why not just learn and understand JS on its own terms?  Book recommendation: [Javascript: The Good Parts, Douglas Crockford](https://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742).  ALSO: consider familiarizing yourself with [Typescript](https://www.guru99.com/typescript-vs-javascript.html).

Comment: @paulsm4 why not just read the question more carefully?

Comment: @paulsm4 Did you mean to comment on a different question?

Comment: "is it a specification to which browser developers adhere" exactly that. In fact you'll find the same kind of interfaces in the Web spec

Comment: I do "understand JS in its own terms", which is why I don't understans "interface" in a language that structurally and philosophically cannot enforce such a contruct. Typescript is not Javascript, and it is not inherent to the question.
Thanks for the answer, however.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not a class with a constructor that you can instantiate, so we don't call it a class. It's not a prototype object either.

MDN uses the term [interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing)#In_object-oriented_languages) in the generic OOP meaning, which is not restricted to class-based inheritance but refers to a type definition with method signatures.

However, it also uses the term [interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#idl-interfaces) in the very specific context of the Web Interface definition language, which the web storage specification uses to [define `Storage` as an `interface`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#storage) indeed. These WebAPIs can be implemented in multiple languages (called "bindings"), though JS is most common. The WebIDL spec even defines [how such an interface is to be represented in JavaScript](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#es-interfaces) (the "ECMAScript binding"), in particular that the linear inheritance of interfaces is implemented using prototype inheritance between interface objects and their `.prototype`s (basically as if using `class Storage extends …`). This means `localStorage instanceof Storage` and `Storage.prototype.hasOwnProperty('getItem')` work as expected.

Comment: How is this intended to work for interfaces whose interface object's don't define a `constructor`. The spec says: `Interface objects whose interfaces are not declared with a constructor operation will throw when called, both as a function and as a constructor.`

Comment: @Jankapunkt it just means that you cannot call `new Storage()` or `Storage()` yourself, but still the "instances" created by the browser will inherit from `Storage.prototype`