# Why can't I obtain a memory-backed implementation of the Storage interface from the Web Storage API?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, session-storage, web-storage

Refs: [Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#storage), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage)

If I wanted an object that implements the API of the `Storage` interface — but not for the persistence (backed only by memory):

I understand that I could re-implement it on my own using a custom class, backed by a string [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) ([example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEDK0EsC2AHEBTJ6B2AXGsuA9gE5gDm60A3gFDTQDESYKAXNALKsA8EuJBNnIAaaP0HCAfAG5a9aMCLYJAV2DES0ABQBKGgoa4AFgggA6Zq2gBeaNnQB3Lqz1yGAX3kNKuaBmETHV0ObFUkACN0LToGBhJ0XFUSbGgTM0sWFHMIBAAvdHdoLwUAa3QATx0hABN0AA9Q8KiSEPtVEBBoAB9xASFyAzjEADMdQziAQgA5ZujzMwAxIQRcdG1aht0Jhm7ezfroHmgABh2e-ew6w6k7dIsrbNyCif0EpJT2zrkJg9sXEzmEYgIikDZXLZFBhKFR+VbRf73TKsczlCoQNwTEakHQYOH-E4yRBHRAQ+pEhDQADUdgAjPp4SRzA56rhMcN3slUozmQ02bpzAA3MAgVToSZFEoMCCJACSayQOjRHAkAzEwtF6BV-WEbUFRAQNSGcSRjxyiW0hEk5G0aN0YitA20GrFul0ku80F88swSsq2utbTCnR6fWtxviiS5aVMDyy5l8lp1Nrt+gA-GmviAPQoEkgiIL0D7Fbb-WGBnqDUbYibY8jsnU8etHcJSxU3TnoRgwFo9Bx9YaIzGMmbQOge+zirQvEA)) — but is there some objective, technical reason that there's no way to simply create one? Basically: all of the code to do it is already there — why do I need to implement my own?

```js
const genericStorage = new Storage(); // throws TypeError (expected)
```

To be clear: I'm **not** asking why the code example above throws a [`TypeError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError) or why `Storage` isn't constructible according to the spec.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript interfaces in MDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67050557/javascript-interfaces-in-mdn)

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75334558/why-cant-i-obtain-a-unique-instance-of-storage-from-the-web-storage-api#comment132930143_75334558) @PeterB Thanks for the link. That doesn't address my question — I'm not asking "Why can't I construct an instance of `Storage`?" or "Why isn't `Storage` constructible?" Rather: why is there no way to get a copy of its API functionality (without the persistence) without having to write my own custom class?

Comment: Where would expect `Storage` to actually "store" the values? The implementation of the API (what you seem to want, if I understand correctly) strongly depends on how the data is actually stored.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75334558/why-cant-i-obtain-a-unique-instance-of-storage-from-the-web-storage-api#comment132930329_75334558) @FelixKling In memory.  How? Not especially important to me — maybe something like a string `Map` as stated in the question.

Comment: [^ @PeterB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75334558/why-cant-i-obtain-a-unique-instance-of-storage-from-the-web-storage-api#comment132930143_75334558) [^ @FelixKling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75334558/why-cant-i-obtain-a-unique-instance-of-storage-from-the-web-storage-api#comment132930329_75334558) Thanks both: I've updated the question in response to your comments to clarify those things.

Comment: *"is there some objective, technical reason that there's no way to simply instantiate one?"* Storage is just an interface. You cannot instantiate an interface. The implementation of the methods depend on *how* the data is stored and the spec only provides implementations for session and local storage, but not for in-memory storage. If you want that you have to write your own implementation.

Comment: If the question is *"is there a technical reason why the spec doesn't define an in-memory Storage implementation"* then I don't know. You might have to find somebody who worked on this or follows spec development closely.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75334558/why-cant-i-obtain-a-unique-instance-of-a-storage-like-object-from-the-web-stora#comment132930596_75334558) @FelixKling Thanks again, I can see how some of the word choices in the initial question might have been misleading. It was never specifically about instantiating a class, and I have clarified that further.

Comment: In the question you ask *"Is there some objective, technical reason that there's no way to simply **create one**?"* but in the comment you say *"It was never specifically about instantiating a class"*. That's contradicting to me. I'm sorry but I don't understand what your asking or what kind of answer you are looking for...

Comment: Using a plain object or, as you suggest, a Map, is *so extremely easy* that it's hard to understand why you'd need anything else. The whole point of the Storage APIs is that they store values for a long time and between page reloads. If all you need is transient in-memory storage, that's literally what *every other* data structure in JavaScript provides (including the DOM from the browser).

Comment: Perhaps if you would describe what you would like to actually do with the facility you want, instead of asking why the W3C didn't spec something out and encourage browser maintainers to implement it, then other people might actually understand what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "objective, technical reason" (as explained in the comments) is that `Storage` is an abstract interface and can't be instantiated.

To reframe this: what would be the "objective, technical reason" for a `new Storage()` to be backed by transient memory? If you ask me, nothing – that'd be a `MemoryStorage`.